# What is the difference between JAXP and JAXB?

Tags: java, xml

What is the difference between JAXP and JAXB?

Comment: FYI, see Oracle Tutorials [for JAXP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/TOC.html) and [for JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/TOC.html).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

JAXP (Java API for XML Processing) is a rather outdated umbrella term covering the various low-level XML APIs in JavaSE, such as DOM, SAX and StAX.

JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding) is a specific API (the stuff under `javax.xml.bind`) that uses annotations to bind XML documents to a java object model.

Comment: In addition to parsing (DOM, SAX, etc.,) I believe JAXP also includes the APIs for tasks like evaluating XPath, performing XSLT transformations and validating XML against a schema. I remember using `javax.xml.validation` classes to validate incoming requests against my service's XSDs, in order to help clients troubleshoot issues themselves.

Answer (score 51):

JAXP is Java API for XML Processing, which provides a platform for us to Parse the XML Files with the DOM Or SAX Parsers.

Where as JAXB is Java Architecture for XML Binding, it will make it easier to access XML documents from applications written in the Java programming language.

For Example : Computer.xml File, if we want to access the data with JAXP, we will be performing the following steps

1. Create a SAX Parser or DOM Parser and then PArse the data, if we use
   DOM, it may be memory intensive if the document is too big. Suppose
   if we use SAX parser, we need to identify the beginning of the
   document. When it encounters something significant (in SAX terms, an
   "event") such as the start of an XML tag, or the text inside of a
   tag, it makes that data available to the calling application.
2. Then Create a content handler that defines the methods to be
   notified by the parser when it encounters an event. These methods,
   known as callback methods, take the appropriate action on the data
   they receive.

***The Same Operations if it is performed by JAXB, the following steps needs to be performed to access the Computer.xml***

1. Bind the schema for the XML document.
2. Unmarshal the document into Java content objects. The Java content objects represent the content and organization of the XML document, and are directly available to your program.
   After unmarshalling, your program can access and display the data in the XML document simply by accessing the data in the Java content objects and then displaying it. There is no need to create and use a parser and no need to write a content handler with callback methods. What this means is that developers can access and process XML data without having to know XML or XML processing

Comment: DOM treats the XML file as object, wheres as SAX handles individual items as events, which is more effecient?

Comment: @Malwaregeek : It depends on the situation, SAX is preferable if you are accessing the entire XML in its sequential order as it takes lesser memory. DOM is preferable if you want random access of middle elements in an XML But it needs more memory. This balance is similar to memory Vs Time space balance in every program

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is which role the xml Schema plays. JAXP is outdated without awareness of the XML Schema while JAXB handles the schema binding as the very first step.

Comment: The JAXP ([JSR 206](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=206)) tutorial, in the [“Implementing SAX Validation”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/validation.html) part, provides a section dedicated to “Validating with XML Schema”. The specification also mentions the [Schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) class as part of the JAXP API. (It has been withdrawn as a standalone project following its inclusion in OpenJDK 7, see section 11.5 in the specification PDF of JAXP 1.6.)